# Why '$' can be omitted within let construct

Tags: bash, syntax, scripting

The `$` sign can be omitted within the `let` and `(( ... ))` constructs.

Why is that so, given that `$` is mandatory when using `if` or `while`?

Comment: Because the $ is placed before the (( hence specifying that the variables within the double brackets need to be expanded.

Comment: I think this comes from ksh, so the answer would be _because David Korn wanted so when he added `$(())`, `(())` and `let` to his shell_.

Comment: As an aside: you may be thinking of `[` / `[[` with respect to mandatory `$`, not `if` and `while` per se, given that `let` and `((...))` can also be used as the conditionals for `if` and `while`; e.g., `if let 'foo == 1'; then echo yes; else echo no; fi` or `if (( foo == 1 )); then echo yes; else echo no; fi`.

Comment: @RamanSailopal: Please note that the question is about use of `$` _inside_ `(( … ))`, in order to reference variables, not about the difference between `(( … ))` and `$(( … ))`. Also, whether and with what syntax variables are expanded inside is independent of whether `(( … ))` or `$(( … ))` is chosen - the only difference is that the latter _outputs_ the result of the arithmetic calculation, whereas the former does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arithmetic expressions deal *only* with integers, not strings. So if a string appears in an expression, the only sensible way to interpret it is as a variable to expand (recursively, as necessary) until you get an integer.

In other contexts, strings are allowed, so the only way to differentiate between the string `foo` and the value of the variable `foo` is to have an explicit syntax for parameter expansion (`foo` is a string, `$foo` produces the value of the parameter `foo`).

The root of all this is that shells do not pass variables to functions or commands; you effectively just expand macros and pass the resulting values.

Answer (score 0):

```
((i++)) or let i++
```

just increments the i. It is an operation performed on a value.
It returns **nothing** but an exit code.

```
var=$((i+2))
```

expands $((i+2)) to its sum.
It returns a **result**.

Comment: it is not true; if i is 0, ((++i)) will return 0 - success on non zero result; ((i++)) will return 1 - false, because it become incremented after

Comment: Well, I meant in arithmetic context, not the exit-code-boolean one. Made some edits.

Comment: True, but the question was about use of `$` _inside_ `(( … ))`, in order to reference variables, not about the difference between `(( … ))` and `$(( … ))`.
To avoid the terminology confusion, I suggest using the word _return_ only to refer to exit codes, whereas data produced is _[stdout] output_. In other words: `$((…))` produces _output_, whereas `((…))` and `let` do not. All of them - invariably, as _any_ command - return an exit code.